# Excel to automatically choose next item on the list

Tags: excel

I'm working on an Excel sheet in Office 360 to help run a pool tournament at my local pool room. I have a list of available table numbers in A1:A10 (Table 1, Table 2, Table 3, etc.). In cells A1:A64 of another sheet, I have all the matches being played. Is there a way to have excel automatically pick any table from the list (which is not currently being used) and populate it?

Comment: Do you update A1:A10 when a table is not free by removing it? What have you tried?

Comment: "Which is not currently being used". What does that mean? If you have 64 matches being played but only 10 tables, then each table will be used 6.4 times. What do you mean here?

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of VBA?

Comment: Please add an example of input and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the desired type of answer for Stack Overflow and I will make sure to give a detailed description of the VBA code behind it this weekend.

I just found the idea super cool and interesting, so I build an Excel file, that does exactly what d219 wants (at least I hope so).

You can find the file here: [here](https://ufile.io/ngqu3)

You will find, that the Excel file has two Sheets "Tables" and "Matches".

In Column A of Tables you just add the table names /numbers. You can delete/add tables simply by deleting/adding names in column A.

In Column A of Matches it works similarly with match names. I just used dummy names for 64 matches. Again replace, add or delete names.

When this is setup, you can simply press "Assign match to empty Table" and matches will be randomly asigned to all free tables. At the same time in the Matches sheet the column "Playing" will be set to "X" indicationg that the match is going on.

When one or multiple matches are finished you select the match names (multiple by keeping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> pressed) and click "Selected Matches Finished". These will be removed from the table und set to "Done" in the Match sheet.

Then you can assign new matches with the first button.

And again I will add the code descriptions at the Weekend.

Cheers and happy Easter!